# Netty server information in a vert.x application

Tags: netty, vert.x

How do I dump the running netty server information (like version, process ID and other server details) in a vert.x application ?

Answer (score 0):

Application internal you can take a look to the package io.netty.util for version information: looks like you can statically call io.netty.util.Version.identify() to get a list of version info. But there are additional utilities such as NetUtil and NettyRuntime that provide ipconfig and instance details.

Not sure if you can get a process ID, perhaps it comes out on the net logging level (-Djavax.net.debug=all)